# Mongo shell query for survey stats($unwind with 2D array)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

My Document Structure(Only 2 given just for the idea):

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edc58af33e9b5988b875fa"),
    "Agent" : {
        "Name" : "NomanAgent",
        "Location" : "Lahore",
        "AgentId" : 66,
        "Suggestion" : [ 
            "Knowledge", 
            "Professionalisn"
        ]
    },
    "Rating" : 2,
    "Status" : "Submitted"
}
/* 2 */
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edc58af33e9b5988b875fb"),
    "Agent" : {
        "Name" : "NomanAgent",
        "Location" : "Lahore",
        "AgentId" : 66,
        "Suggestion" : [ 
            "Knowledge", 
            "Clarity"
        ]
    },
    "Rating" : 1,
    "Status" : "Submitted"
}
/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59edc58af33e9b5988b875fc"),
    "Agent" : {
        "Name" : "NomanAgent",
        "Location" : "Lahore",
        "AgentId" : 66,
        "Reward" : "Thumb Up"
    },
    "Rating" : 5,
    "Status" : "Submitted"
}
```

These are basically the survey responses, so an Agent object could contain either a Suggestion(in case of bad customer review) or a Reward(in case of a happy customer) so here I am showing 2 documents with Suggestions and 1 with Reward.

I have created a query for the Rewards which is given below,

```
db.getCollection('_survey.response').aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$Agent.Name",
            Rating: {$avg: "$Rating"},
            Rewards: {$push: "$Agent.Reward"},
            Status: {$push : "$Status"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Rewards"  
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                Agent: "$_id",
                Rating: "$Rating",
                Rewards: "$Rewards"
            },
            RewardCount:{$sum: 1},
            SurveyStatus: {$first: "$Status"}

        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$_id.Agent",
            Rewards: {$push:{Reward: "$_id.Rewards", Count: "$RewardCount"}},
            Rating: {$first: "$_id.Rating"},
            SurveyStatus: {$first: "$SurveyStatus"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$SurveyStatus"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                Agent: "$_id",
                Survey: "$SurveyStatus"
            },
            StatusCount:{$sum : 1},
            Rating: {$first: "$Rating"},
            Rewards: {$first: "$Rewards"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$_id.Agent",
            Status:{$push:{Status: "$_id.Survey", Count: "$StatusCount"}},
            Rewards: {$first: "$Rewards"},
            Rating: {$first: "$Rating"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            _id: 0,
            Agent: "$_id",
            Rating: {
                $multiply:[
                    {$divide:["$Rating",5]},
                    100
                ]
            },
            Status: 1,
            Rewards: 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Above query works perfectly fine for the rewards, i want exactly the same thing for suggestions and i would be happy if its possible to adjust Suggestions in the same query(We can also create a separate query for suggestion).

Response of above given query:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "Status" : [ 
        {
            "Status" : "Submitted",
            "Count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "Status" : "Pending",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Status" : "Opened",
            "Count" : 2.0
        }
    ],
    "Rewards" : [ 
        {
            "Reward" : "Thumb Up",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Reward" : "Thank You",
            "Count" : 2.0
        }
    ],
    "Agent" : "GhazanferAgent",
    "Rating" : 68.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Status" : [ 
        {
            "Status" : "Opened",
            "Count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "Status" : "Viewed",
            "Count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "Status" : "Pending",
            "Count" : 3.0
        }
    ],
    "Rewards" : [ 
        {
            "Reward" : "Gift",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "Reward" : "Thumb Up",
            "Count" : 3.0
        }, 
        {
            "Reward" : "Thank You",
            "Count" : 1.0
        }
    ],
    "Agent" : "NomanAgent",
    "Rating" : 60.0
}
```

What I have tried so far, I think of two approaches but find an issue with each of them,

> First(Find avg rating and push status and suggestions in array):

```
db.getCollection("_survey.response").aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            $and:[
                {
                    "Agent.Suggestion":{
                        $exists: true
                    }
                },    
                {
                    Rating: {$lte: 3}
                }
            ]

        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                AgentName: "$Agent.Name",
                AgentId: "$Agent.AgentId",
                Location: "$Agent.Location"
            },
            Rating: {$avg: "$Rating"},
            Status: {$push : "$Status"},
            Suggestions: {$push: "$Agent.Suggestion"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Issue facing with this approach is, suggestions in the projection will become an array of arrays(as it was initially an array) of dynamic size depending on the number of times an agent gets a suggestion in a customer response. So the problem is applying **$unwind on 2D array of dynamic size**.

> Second($unwind the suggestions in the first stage as its a 1D array
>   to avoid $unwind issue on 2D array of dynamic size)

```
db.getCollection("_survey.response").aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            $and:[
                {
                    "Agent.Suggestion":{
                        $exists: true
                    }
                },    
                {
                    Rating: {$lte: 3}
                }
            ]

        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Agent.Suggestion"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:{
                AgentName: "$Agent.Name",
                AgentId: "$Agent.AgentId",
                Suggestion: "$Agent.Suggestion",
                Location: "$Agent.Location"
            },
            Status: {$push: "$Status"},
            Rating: {$avg: "$Rating"},
            Count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
]);
```

Problem using this approach is **$unwind Suggestion array** it will flatten all suggestion with their respective agents thus increasing the number of documents(as compared to original responses) **so i won't be able to find correct value for average rating for each agent on the basis of this grouping and the same will happen the Status(Because i can correctly find these two fields only if i group by agent. While, here i am grouping with agent along with suggestion)**,

I want exactly the same response for Suggestion query, only the Rewards object in response would replace Suggestions(Or it would great if we could get Suggestions object in the same response)

Survey Status can be, pending, Opened,viewed, Submitted etc

Output explanation:

I want suggestions(with counts), status(with counts) and Rating in % form(which i am already doing) for each of the agent as you can see in the output mentioned above.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You have create quite sophisticated pipeline for rewards. What stops you to do the same for Suggestions?

Comment: Rewards is simply a key value pair, while Suggestions is an array this is where i am stuck, it mess with Rating(which is being calculated in % form in project stage) when i unwind to flatten the data of Suggestions.

Comment: I might be wrong , i just want to convert this query for suggestion some how.

Comment: Rewards is an array after the first stage. It may worth to add your attempts where it "mess"  with the Ratings to the question. It's not quite clear what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Using $unwind two consecutive times did the trick for me, using First approach,

```
db.getCollection("_survey.response").aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            $and:[
                {
                    "Agent.Suggestion":{
                        $exists: true
                    }
                },    
                {
                    Rating: {$lte: 3}
                }
            ]

        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                AgentName: "$Agent.Name",
                AgentId: "$Agent.AgentId",
                Location: "$Agent.Location"
            },
            Rating: {$avg: "$Rating"},
            Status: {$push : "$Status"},
            Suggestions: {$push: "$Agent.Suggestion"}
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Suggestions"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Suggestions"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                Suggestions: "$Suggestions",
                AgentName: "$_id.AgentName",
                AgentId: "$_id.AgentId",
                Location: "$_id.Location"
            },
            SuggestionCount: {$sum: 1},
            Rating: {$first: "$Rating"},
            Status: {$first: "$Status"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
           _id:{
                AgentName: "$_id.AgentName",
                AgentId: "$_id.AgentId",
                Location: "$_id.Location"
            },
            Suggestions: {$push:{Sugestion: "$_id.Suggestions", Count: "$SuggestionCount"}},
            TotalSuggestions: {$sum: "$SuggestionCount"},
            Rating: {$first: "$Rating"},
            Status: {$first: "$Status"}
        }

    },
    {
        $unwind: "$Status"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                AgentName: "$_id.AgentName",
                AgentId: "$_id.AgentId",
                Location: "$_id.Location",
                Status: "$Status"
            },
            StatusCount:{$sum : 1},
            Rating: {$first: "$Rating"},
            Suggestions: {$first: "$Suggestions"},
            TotalSuggestions: {$first: "$TotalSuggestions"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                AgentName: "$_id.AgentName",
                AgentId: "$_id.AgentId",
                Location: "$_id.Location"
            },
            Status:{$push:{Status: "$_id.Status", Count: "$StatusCount"}},
            TotalStatus: {$sum: "$StatusCount"},
            Suggestions: {$first: "$Suggestions"},
            TotalSuggestions: {$first: "$TotalSuggestions"},
            Rating: {$first: "$Rating"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            AgentName: "$_id.AgentName",
            AgentId: "$_id.AgentId",
            Location: "$_id.Location",
            Status: 1,
            TotalStatus: 1,
            Suggestions: 1,
            TotalSuggestions: 1,
            Performance: {
                $concat: [
                    {
                        $substr: [
                            {
                                $multiply:[
                                    {$divide:["$Rating",5]},
                                    100
                                ]

                            }, 0, 4
                        ]
                    },"%"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```